# Different actions for one button on form

Tags: extjs

i am have form with tabpanel (tabpanel have two tab). On the form i have one button (name:start), and i am want: when selecting the first tab -> button does one action when selecting the second tab -> another action.

this is in controller:

```
    showCreateForm: function(button) {
    actions...
},
```

what condition need to write in controller ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question....

ExtJs have one advantage that is, to listen a element's action by using its path and some unique attribute for example Inside_Some_XType->TabPanel->TabName->Button so try this manner...

see the following example what i did in my project before, it will helps you

watch in the ref section, how we did this...

```
Ext.define("XCP.controller.LoginController", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    views: ["LoginScreen"],
    refs: [
            //Ext.ComponentQuery
            { ref: "userName", selector: "login > textfield[id=usernametext]" },
            { ref: "password", selector: "login > textfield[inputType=password]" },
            { ref: "homeScreen", selector: "home" }
    ],
    init: function () {
        this.control({
            "login > button[text=Submit]": {
                click: this.onLoginButtonClicked
            },
            "login > button[text=Reset]": {
                click: this.onResetButtonClicked
            },
            "#logoutbutton": {
                click: this.onLogoutButtonClicked
            }
        });
    },
    onLogoutButtonClicked: function () {
        this.application.viewport.getLayout().setActiveItem(0);
    },
    onResetButtonClicked: function () {
        alert("Reset");
    },
    onLoginButtonClicked: function () {
        if (this.getUserName().getValue() == "admin" &&
                this.getPassword().getValue() == "admin") {
            if(!this.getHomeScreen())
                this.application.viewport.add({ xtype: "home", id: "homescreen" });
            this.application.viewport.getLayout().setActiveItem(1);
        }
        else
            alert("Invalid credentials");
    }
});
```

otherwise you should generate default and unique id for button in each tab... its not highly recommenced.

Answer (score 0):

oh thanks, and i am should write refs in my controller about this?:

```
refs: [ 
{ ref: "sellBook", selector: "bookgrid>TabPanel>Tab1>button[action=check-book]"}, 
{ ref: "buyBook", selector: "bookgrid>TabPanel>Tab2>button[action=check-book]" }, 
],) 

init: function () 
{ this.control(

{ "bookgrid > button[action=check-book]": { click: this.sellBookShow },
{ "bookgrid> button[action=check-book]": { click: this.buyBookShow }, })
```

Comment: thanks, i am make this with two conditions   if (activeTab == 'tab1') {...} else if {...}